# string indices must be integers json

Tags: python

i have a json data https://steamcommunity.com/id/RednelssGames/inventory/json/730/2
need get names of all the items

```
r = requests.get('https://steamcommunity.com/id/RednelssGames/inventory/json/730/2')
if r.json()['success'] == True:
     for rows in r.json()['rgDescriptions']:
         print(rows['market_hash_name'])
```

getting error string indices must be integers

Comment: You have not provided enough information for someone else to execute this code.

Comment: @ScottHunter he has !

Comment: Well this surely is not [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `cookies`=?  `headers`=?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the for-loop as follows:

```py
                for rows in r.json()['rgDescriptions'].values():
                    print(rows['market_hash_name'])
```

By iterating over a dictionary like you did, you get the **keys** and not the values (rows). If you want to iterate over the values, you have to iterate over the return value of `dict.values()`.

Answer (score 0):

From the link you provided:

```
"rgDescriptions":{"4291220570_302028390":
```

`rgDescriptions` doesn't return an array, but an object (a dictionary, in this case) (notice the opening curly brace (`{`) rather than a regular square brace (`[`)).

By using `for rows in r.json()['rgDescriptions']:` you end up iterating over the dictionary's keys. The first key of the dictionary seems to be `"4291220570_302028390"`, which is a string.

so when you do `print(rows['market_hash_name'])`, you're attempting to access the `'market_hash_name'` "index" of your `rows` object, but `rows` is actually a string, so it doesn't work.

Comment: How can I fix this? :c